# drush cc all giving me an unlink error

Tags: drush

I found a similar issue but it will not help me since I have not changed permissions.

I am running drush cc all and getting this error...

[image]

I have logged out and back in and nothing. I have not changed permissions and I have the admin rights to the account. Any ideas on what to do?

Comment: Can you post an example of those permissions? And, which is the similiar issue?

Comment: You say: "I have the admin rights to the account".  What account is that and what exactly do you mean by "admin rights"?  Also: who owns the directory and files that produces the error?  What is written when you type the CLI command `whoami` ?

Comment: The hosting account is with blackmesh. So, whoami gives me the account name. Should I send this to them to make sure I have access to that folder?

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this problem when as unprivileged user you call drush cc all and drush tries to delete cache files created by the web server process. Those files are owned by the web server user and they don't have the 'all other users" write permissions enabled (the last three permissions group).

Fixing this is a file permissions issue. One fix is to put web server user and drush user in the same group and assure that files created by the web server process are writable by its group members.

Comment: So, if I am hosted with someone like blackmesh do I need to ask them to set the permissions so I can run it properly?

Comment: To answer properly I need the file permissions, group and owner of one of the files with error and the user name you use to run drush (use whoami command).

Comment: Okay, redoing the permissions did the job. I am now able to run drush cc all without any issues. Thank you for you help!!!

Comment: If the answer is correct you may indicate it by selecting this answer as the accepted answer. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235